# how we put integer validation on text box in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making a Wpf Application. I want to put validations on integer and character textboxes.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Just a hint. For Integer validation and conversion use int.TryParse. For the rest - I donno, regular expressions in the worst case scenario. I just don't get what the big question is.

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an Exception when values are out of range and use ValidationRules like this:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Number">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

More information can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpfvalidation.aspx

Update:
In code behind you can do something like:

```
private int _Number;
public string Number
{
    get { return  _Number.ToString(); }
    set
    {
        if (!Int32.TryParse(value, out _Number))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Invalid integer number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the answer to include code behind. hopefully it is what you expected.