# How to validate for a "." in a textbox with c#

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

Hello everyone I am trying to validate a textbox in winforms which is going to pass data to a store procedure which contain an Int as parameter. I have been looking for a function that checks if the input contains "." in it so I can add a warning box to it but didn't find any. Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: Which UI framework? Did you try searching? You're not the first who wants to do this.

Comment: why stop at simply looking for a full stop? why not search for a non-numeric character?

Comment: TextBox- but which GUI framework are you using?

Comment: Nice to know that on my German Windows 1,23 would be a valid `int` :-)

Comment: I would strongly suggest to search for a `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;` instead of a "." since i.e. on my system you couldn't find a decimal separator by looking for a period character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following tries to convert the text value to `int` and detects errors. The good thing about it is that is does not only check for invalid characters, but also considers maximum/minimum values.

```
int result;
if (!Int32.TryParse(textBox.Text, out result))
{
   // The textbox did not contain an int
}
```

In case you are using WPF or ASP.NET you might want to look into "validators" to show errors in the UI right away. For WPF [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and for ASP.NET [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debza5t0.aspx).

Comment: That's the best solution since it not only verifies for the dot, it also makes sure the value is an Integer. If the user types a char or use a comma (which is the decimal separator in Germany and Brazil, for example)

Comment: thank you this is the best solution for my situation

Answer (score 0):

You could simply just check the text with `contains`.

```
txt_input.Text.Contains(".")
```

And display the error message as your ui needs it.

**Update:**

In case you are using WPF you can get this done automatically:
[how we put integer validation on text box in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802501/3322037)

Comment: what if the user enters `1,23` (many cultures use the comma as decimal separator) or a simple typo like `1q23`?

Comment: @user1666620 Well, this answer answers the OP's question to the letter, but the question itself is questionable...

Comment: Then you could use the solution of @Thorsten Dittmar. But as the OP asked my anwser finds the "." inside the textbox. Or you could use some regex to find any non numeric characters in the textbox.

Comment: @JoeJoe87577 Sometimes doing exactly what you were told to do means you do not actually fix the problem. Regarding using a regex, there's an old joke - you've used a regex to solve a problem. Now you have 2 problems.

Comment: Well yes, regex is a pain in the ***. But for such simple scenarios it is quite usefull. And there are plenty of regex builders, validators and interactive cheat sheets online.

Comment: thank you :) this is pretty much what i needed, i'll have to make more research about cultures and validation techniques

Answer (score -1):

Well, after the down votes, I am updating this answer after *4 years* with a better solution to do. In a sense that the previous solution would be ignored.

**Solution 1:**

```
public bool IsNumber(string strToValidate)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(strToValidate, @"^[0-9]+$"); // Using Regex
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
public bool IsNumber(string strToValidate)
{
    foreach (char c in strToValidate)
    {
        if (c < '0' || c > '9')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Solution 3:** Just to make the Solution 2 a one liner:

```
bool isNumber = strToValidate.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9');
```

Comment: Better to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;` instead of `"."` since there is no guarantee that the decimal separator will be a period character.